# Link recognition in custom UITableview cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uitextview, drawrect

I have an app where i use custom table cells.The problem is that i want to have url,email,phone number and fabebook link recognition on them.I tried it by adding uitextviews as subviews to cell which naturally caused some performance problems.What could be alternative to implement such a feature without causing performance problems on scrolling?

Comment: some code to support your question would be good.... what problems are you facing??

Comment: @IronLeash Y cant you just add it as a label?

Comment: I do not think text views would cause a perfomance problem. Maybe you forgot to disable scrolling. Nested scrollviews may cause problems.

Comment: if you have 100 messages with custom cells with links and images inside it really matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days ago i found the the TTTAttributedLabel and that works great.All i needed was implementing URL extractor function to detect fabebook links and mark them as links.
Right now no more scrolling issues.

https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel